# Indexação registros BD

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados, índices

Recentemente rodei um `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` no meu banco de dados que é razoavelmente grande, cerca de 800mil registros em algumas tabelas, e notei que os métodos de indexação adotados não eram os melhores . Sempre deixei que o banco decidisse qual era a melhor forma de indexar os registros, só que tenho notado que é algo comum o erro da escolha do método, logo:

- Existem boas práticas para a indexação de arquivos no banco de dados?
- Conhecendo o meu conjunto de dados, como posso saber qual é a melhor
  técnica de indexação?
- Existem ferramentas, além do próprio BD, que possam me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Não consigo comentar, por isto vou por em forma de resposta.

O banco vai se basear no `ANALYZE`[1] para ter certeza de estar tomando a decisão certa. Lembre sempre de manter o autoanalize forte o bastante.

Verifique se a tabela que você está monitorando rodou um analyze e quando foi a última vez; e se necessário, faça manualmente:

```
SELECT relname, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum, last_analyze, last_autoanalyze, n_tup_ins, n_tup_upd, n_tup_del, n_dead_tup 
FROM pg_stat_all_tables  
WHERE schemaname = 'public'
AND relname = 'tablename'
;
```

Dificilmente o banco fará uma decisão errada quanto a isto. Para termos mais ideia do que está acontecendo, seria bom você postar aqui alguns dados, como o `output da query` a cima, e o `explain analyze` da query que você rodou.

[1] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html